# Is it possible to program a "Security Group" firewall rule, including the source ports?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'd like the Security Group firewall to perform stateless filtering, of incoming traffic, based on only the source ports.  IBM's web page states that Security Group firewall rules are "five-tuples", including "source and destination port".

[IBM's Web Page - Security Group Firewall Five Tuple](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/network-security-groups)

Via the GUI, it only said Security Group "port range", but there was no source and destination "port range" so I assume that the "port range" is only destination port range.  Maybe IBM's web page contains a mistake or maybe the five-tuple is only supported via the CLI.

Is it possible, via the CLI, to create a Security Group Firewall rule with state-less filtering on "source port"?

BTW: Related to this, Microsoft Azure and Amazon AWS support stateless source port filtering, but Google GCP does not. I know bluemix supports this source port range on the Juniper firewall solution, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/security-groups?topic=security-groups-creating-a-new-rule

Answer (score 1):

Security Group rules are stateful. Once you set up a rule and communication is established accordingly, response traffic is allowed. Therefore it is not necessary to specify source or destination ports as part of a security group rule.

For IBM Cloud Virtual Private Cloud, Network ACLs complement Security Groups and provide stateless rules including Source IP and Port ranges: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vpc-on-classic-network?topic=vpc-on-classic-network-setting-up-network-acls

For IBM Cloud classic infrastructure, there are several firewall options that include the ability to specify source ports. The firewall choices are listed here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/fortigate-10g?topic=fortigate-10g-exploring-firewalls

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear that I'm only interested in stateless incoming source port filtering.